Can a game file gain data without changing the properties of created, modify or accessed due to packet bursts or extrapolation?
I would play a game and I keep track of my file sizes using properties. While I would play I would get warnings of packet burst and extrapolation in various colors. Then I would check the game file properties and my file size would be larger by gigs of data and the same dates would be still listed in created, modify and accessed.
I tried to use any and all links for solving my packet burst and extrapolation problem since I thought it was when the transfer of data might have occurred since I never updated the game to get the data and the dates on the properties were the same
